# A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred while convert partial json to c# object

Tags: c#, json

So, here I have `JsonResult jr`, it looks like this(the output is one single line, I format it here):

```
string jr = {"Results":
    [
      {"Code":"DEMO",
       "Id":"1285",
       "Office":"9881",
       "Customers":
           [
             2713,
             94204
           ],
       "Account":196,
       "Appointments":
           [
             14,
             58
           ],
       "Role":0,
       "UserName":"demo",
       "UserId":3669,
       "FirstName":"Peter",
       "LastName":"Pan",
       "Phones":
           [
             "(888) 888-8888"
           ],
       "Fax":null,
       "Email":"test@test.com",
       "SMS":null,
       "RecordStatus":"1"},


      {"Code":"DEMO",
       "Id":"9292",
       "Office":"9881",
       "Customers":
           [
             13,
             904
           ],
       "Account":196,
       "Appointments":
           [
             14,
             58
           ],
       "Role":0,
       "UserName":"berry",
       "UserId":302,
       "FirstName":"Jimmy",
       "LastName":"White",
       "Phones":
           [
             "(888) 888-8888"
           ],
       "Email":"test@test.com",
       "SMS":null,
       "RecordStatus":"1"}
     ],
"TotalResults":2,
"MilliSeconds":4}
```

Here is my object `User`:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to use Deserializing Partial JSON Fragments to map the json to my object: 
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

I followed the example, but I got an error: **A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occured in Newtonsoft.Json.dll**.

Many people online saying it's caused by bad json. I checked mine, didn't find anything wrong by myself. Below is my code:

```
JObject response = JObject.Parse(jr);
IList<JToken> results = response["Results"].Children().ToList();

IList<User> searchResults = new List<User>();
foreach(JToken result in results)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result); //just to check my json data.
    User searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(results.ToString()); //get exception on this line.
    searchResults.Add(searchResult);
}
```

The first `result` output looks like this:

```
{
       "Code":"DEMO",
       "Id":"1285",
       "Office":"9881",
       "Customers":
           [
             2713,
             94204
           ],
       "Account":196,
       "Appointments":
           [
             14,
             58
           ],
       "Role":0,
       "UserName":"demo",
       "UserId":3669,
       "FirstName":"Peter",
       "LastName":"Pan",
       "Phones":
           [
             "(888) 888-8888"
           ],
       "Fax":null,
       "Email":"test@test.com",
       "SMS":null,
       "RecordStatus":"1"
}
```

Not sure why this exception happens, wondering how to fix it..

Comment: Have you checked out Json.Net and a custom serializer for your phone values?

Comment: No. I'm new to c#, not quite sure what do you mean..

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json is the go-to JSON library for .Net, it can do what you want though you'll have to add some attributes to your `User` class so the serializer knows what fields go where.

Comment: I got `JsonResult jr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult>(response);`, `response` is a string I got from httprequest. Are you saying, I don't deserialize it to `JsonResult`, instead, I deserialize it to `User` directly?

Comment: The thing is I can't really change `User` class much, because it is used somewhere else. I think I need to keep the structure. I only want to do the mapping thing here.

Comment: Ok, I saw this under the link, [ http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm ], I will try this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line:

```
User searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(result.ToString()) // result and not results
```

you want to deserialize a simple **result** and not the **results**.

Full code:

```
JObject response = JObject.Parse(jr);
IList<JToken> results = response["Results"].Children().ToList();

IList<User> searchResults = new List<User>();
foreach (JToken result in results)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result); //just to check my json data.
    User searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(result.ToString()); //get exception on this line.
    searchResults.Add(searchResult);
}
```

BTW, you can replace the loop with some basic Linq:

```
JObject response = JObject.Parse(jr);
IList<User> searchRes = response["Results"].Select(r => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(r.ToString())).ToList();
```

Comment: Ohhh.... I'm so careless.. yes that's why, it works now. Finally. And thanks for replace my loop. It's much more nice now. :)

Comment: I just want to point out that the way to **convert only part of the json to your own object** is here:[ http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm ]